# Ellipsis in Comparatives (CGEL 2002)

Tags: ellipsis, comparative-constructions

> 1. She is older than I am.
> 2. She is right more often than the others are.
>    ( CGEL page 1108-1109).

The authors said the reduction in 1 is obligatory but 2 is optional (...more than others are right). What is the difference?

Comment: Could it be because, in #2, the word "right" is not part of the comparative *phrase*, and so, it could optionally show up in the comparative *clause*.

Answer (score 3):

SHORT ANSWER:
As F.E. comments, *are right* is not part of the comparative phrase, which involves the 'variable' *often*; so omission of *are right* or just *right* is optional.

LONGER ANSWER:
*COMPer than*, where *COMPer* is an adjective or adverb in the comparative degree (e.g. *older*, *bigger*, *more desirable*, *more often*), expresses the relation between two scalar qualities in two different situations. Syntactically, it relates two underlying clauses:

> A is X. B is Y.

A and B are the situations, and the qualities which are compared are the ‘variables’ X and Y.

Two rules govern what may and may not be omitted when these are combined in the expression *A is Xer than B*

1. COMPARATIVE REDUCTION
   If X and Y measure values of **different** qualities, both **must be included**.

   > A is (so) **tall**. B is (so) **wide**. → A is **taller** than B is **wide**.

   But if they measure the values of **the same** quality, the ‘restatement’ of that quality in the second part **must be omitted**:

   > A is (so) **tall**. B is (so) **tall**. → A is **taller** than B is <s>**tall**</s>.

   Consequently, in your first example, *old* **must** be omitted in the second part.

   > She is **old**. I am **old**. → She is **older** than I am <s>**old**</s>.
2. REPETITIVE REDUCTION
   Any terms which ‘belong’ to both situations, **not** to the comparisons, **may** be omitted in the second part by the ordinary process of ellipsis. This is neither obligatory nor prohibited but optional.

   Your second example compares two values of a single quality, *often*, and the restatement of that quality must, under rule 1, be omitted.

   > She is right **often**. The others are right **often**. → She is right **more often** than the others are right <s>**often**</s>.

   But the situation in the second clause is expressed with a term which is syntactically identical to the term which describes the situation in the first clause: *BE right*. (The morphological difference between *is* and *are* is ‘bracketed out’.) Consequently this term may be truncated or omitted entirely in the restatement, under rule 2.

   > She is right more often than the others are right.
   >   She is right more often than the others are.
   >   She is right more often than the others.

   The ellipsis is optional, so all of these are acceptable.